# Unexpected mod_rewrite behaivor

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a *.htaccess* file with (only) the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/[^/]+\.txt$ a.html [L]
```

What this does is to redirect every URL one directory below the current and ending with `.txt`.

I have two additional files (each containing one line of text for identification):

- a.html
- existent

I have **no file named nonexistent**.

- When I request `nonexistent/some.txt` I get the contents of `a.html`, as *EXPECTED*
- When I request `existent/some.txt` I get the contents of `a.html`, as *EXPECTED*
- When I request `a.html/some.txt` I get a 404 error which was **UNEXPECTED**

*Nothe that I don't have dontent-negotiation enabled. To prove this: `existent/some.html` return 404.*

I am totally baffled by this behavior, I'd like to know what principle is working here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add in (untested):

`RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !/?a\.html`

Comment: Thanks but expicitly excluding `a.html` will only work in this *simplified* example. I just created this to demonstrate the core of the problem.

Comment: So, could you demonstrate what problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: I tried the `RewriteCond` you recommended, but no difference. I'd rather uncover the cause of this problem. According to my experience this should work as it is, but it does not, so I'd like to know what principle do I overlook. It is more important to me than the actual problem.

Comment: Anyway, the real probelm I tried to solve would redirect to `$1` (the first regex pattern), which file(s) do exist.

Comment: Ack, if this doesn't work, have you enabled your RewriteLog at a reasonably high level to check what it does?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in a position currently do do that, but I certainly plan to. In the meantime I guess anyone could easily replicate the scenario. I'm also interested if this is an inssue too on in different environments.